# launching netsh to get the output

Tags: pascal, lazarus

I use this code:

```
proc := TProcess.Create(nil);
strList := TStringList.Create;

proc.Executable := 'netsh.exe';
proc.Parameters.Add('wlan');
proc.Parameters.Add('show');
proc.Parameters.Add('all');
proc.Options := proc.Options + [poWaitOnExit, poUsePipes];

proc.Execute;
strList.LoadFromStream(proc.Output);
proc.Free;
strList.Free;
```

The problem is `netsh` stay on screen (black command window) and do not stop.
If I remove `poUsePipes`, I can see clearly that `netsh` do the right job, output is correct.

Comment: Preferable to call the system api rather than shell to an external process

Answer (score 1):

It works with this code. I've understood the first method (in my question) generate to many bytes in the output so i had a deadlock. Mercy to https://wiki.freepascal.org/Executing_External_Programs (french version for me)

```
const
  READ_BYTES = 2048;
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  proc: TProcess;
  strList: TStringList;
  ms: TMemoryStream;
  n: LongInt;
  br: LongInt;
  i: longint;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ms:=TMemoryStream.Create;
  br:=0;

  proc := TProcess.Create(nil);
  strList := TStringList.Create;

  proc.Executable := 'netsh.exe';
  proc.Parameters.Add('wlan');
  proc.Parameters.Add('show');
  proc.Parameters.Add('all');
  proc.Options := proc.Options + [poUsePipes];
  proc.ShowWindow:=TShowWindowOptions.swoHIDE;

  proc.Execute;
  while proc.Running do
  begin
    ms.SetSize(br + READ_BYTES);
    n:=proc.Output.Read((ms.Memory + br)^, READ_BYTES);
    if n > 0
    then begin
      Inc(br, n);
    end
    else begin
      //no data: wait 100ms
      Sleep(100);
    end;
  end;
  //read last part
  repeat
    ms.SetSize(br + READ_BYTES);
    n:=proc.Output.Read((ms.Memory + br)^, READ_BYTES);
    if n > 0
    then begin
      Inc(br, n);
    end
  until n <= 0;

  ms.SetSize(br);
  strList.LoadFromStream(ms);
  proc.Free;

  for i := 0 to strList.Count - 1 do
  begin
    memo.Append(CP437ToUTF8(strList.Strings[i]));
  end;
  strList.Free;


end;
```

Comment: Better look at the English version of that page, and use runcommand, which is all this wrapped up in a single line command.